# (Wise price comparison) IMPORTXML - Imported content is empty

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

starting my journey as a data analyst. I am trying to web scrape a table off of Transferwise (Wise's) price comparison website. I tried to:

- Copy and paste URL into cell A1 in Google Sheets
- Inspect the table row on the website
- Copy and paste full Xpath into cell A2 in Google Sheets
- Write formula: =importxml(A1,A2)
- Get error

[Inspecting table row on Wise price comparison website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htlHG.png)

[Google Sheets error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHfww.png)

Does IMPORTXML generally not work if the website uses an API to populate the table? The tables do seem different for those on Wikipedia for example.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to retrieve informations by importxml since the page is built by javascript on client side, not server side. What you are lokking for is in fact a script!

```
<script>
          (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://widgets.wise.com/widgets.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
          }(document, "script", "transferwise-wjs"));
</script>
```

see other comments here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun